# "TypeError: callback is not a function" in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I dont know what is reason of this.
response's body.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <script src="/charting_library/charting_library.min.js"></script>
        <title>Charting Library React Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="root"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
"
```

expect body
{
ret_code: 0 //success.
}

help me please...thank you.

The status code is 200 ok, but respond is "./node_modules/stream-http/lib/response.js.exports.IncomingMessage.".
How do i have to get correct response?

My code following as

```
componentDidMount() {
        // Example of use 
        var req = new MT5Request("localhost", 443); 
    
        // Authenticate on the server using the Auth command 
        req.Auth(111, "passwd",  1985, "WebManager",  function (error) { 
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error); 
                return; 
            } 
            
        });
    }


///auth function
MT5Request.prototype.Auth = function (login, password, build, agent, callback) { 
  if (!login || !password || !build || !agent) 
    return; 
  var self = this; 
  self.Get("/api/auth/start?version=" + build + "&agent=" + agent + "&login=" + login + "&type=manager", function (error, res, body) { 
    var answer = self.ParseBodyJSON(error, res, body, callback); 
    if (answer) { 
      var srv_rand_answer = self.ProcessAuth(answer, password); 
      var cli_random_buf = crypto.randomBytes(16); 
      var cli_random_buf_hex = cli_random_buf.toString('hex'); 
      self.Get("/api/auth/answer?srv_rand_answer=" + srv_rand_answer + "&cli_rand=" + cli_random_buf_hex, function (error, res, body) { 
        var answer = self.ParseBodyJSON(error, res, body, callback); 
        if (answer) { 
          if (self.ProcessAuthFinal(answer, password, cli_random_buf)) 
            callback && callback(null); 
          else 
            callback && callback("invalid final auth answer"); 
        } 
      }); 
    } 
  }); 
  return (true); 
};
```

Comment: show the code??

Comment: The error says `callback` is not a function, but you've called `callback(null, res, body)`.  That's what the error means.  For example, `foo = undefined;  foo()` will give the same error.  Can you please do the basic debugging?  If `callback` is not a function, as you apparently intended it to be, then what was it instead?  There's insufficient detail in your question to diagnose this and you haven't shown the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply calling the `callback()` function line 28:

> callback(null, res, body);

But this function doesn't seem to exist, no function named `callback` is natively present in javascript (Try to open your browser's console or a simple node.js terminal and type `callback()` and you will see it doesn't exist.

May shall you show us the code ?